# Avg Antivirus Network- Scan results not showing up

Tags: windows

I recently upgraded our AVG antivirus network security to 8.5 on all machines, set everything up per the instructions (and actually removed and reinstalled everything), and I have confirmed that scans are running per the schedule set up via AVG Admin Console, and it downloads updates and the clients grab updates from it okay, and it shows the correct version of the virus db and program.

However, scan results will not show up in the scan results screen of AVG Admin Console. If I start a scan manually from the Admin Console, it starts on the client fine, and everything else works great...

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just got an email from AVG's tech support after going back and forth a little explaining the issue and sending them some logs. Here's what they said:

> a).. Launch AVG Admin Console.
> b) Click on 'Data Center' -- > 'AVG Data Center settings'.
> c). Under 'Scan result options' select 'All Scan results'.
> d) Click 'Ok' to save changes.
>
> Now perform a new synchronization and verify if the scan results can be displayed.

And now it works.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an answer other than to say that the AVG client sometimes fails to write scan results to the central database. For example I have a network where the PCs do update the scan results but the server doesn't.

If you look in "C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\avg8\scanlogs" on the PC you should see the scan logs, though they're binary files so not much use. However the last modified time at least tells you that the scan ran and when it finished.

On the PC running the Admin console you'll find a SQL database called avg8, and if you run the query:

```
select * from avg_scanlogs
where avg_scanstarted > '2009-07-01'
order by avg_scanstarted desc
```

it will show you what data is in the database. In the case of the network mentioned above the server scanlogs aren't in the database even though the log files are present and the scan takes a couple of hours so it's obviously not bombing out.

Actually, I've just had a thought. I'll have to look into this, but it may be that the scan results are only getting written to the database if someone is logged in. I'll the aforementioned server logged in tonight to see if the scan results get recorded.

JR

Edit: leaving the server logged in made no difference. It still did not log the scan results to the database. As Cameron says in his comment, requesting the scan results apparently works but fails to send any data. It's down to a bug in AVG8.5 I guess.

Comment: You can try it on your server, however my server is just a windows xp box that runs AVG and our backup of the NAS (small business).. It stays logged in all the time, and I've tried it with the Console open and shut, and at least on my server, it doesn't show up either way. Also tried it both ways with scheduled scans and scans forced via the Console.. Interested in hearing your experiences..

Comment: Just thought of something: I've also clicked the 'get scan results' menu option for stations. The log shows the command goes out, and the logs have sync'd, but nothing shows up.

Most annoying thing is that avg 7.5 worked flawlessly.